# Does anyone know of a free solution to perform failover for VMware ESXi?

Tags: replication, vmware, virtualization, failover, disaster-recovery

I would like to setup a free/custom solution to perform failover for VMware ESXi.

The setup is as follows:

2x Physical servers each with independent storage.
For each physical server there are 2x Win2k8 Enterprise servers.

In the case a physical server completely fails, we want the other (for convenience sake we can assign it with a slave role) to resume operation.

For this to occur, we need to somehow do continuous replication of the virtual servers, and in the case of the primary server failing have it take over the IP, start the virtual machines and continue operation.

I am new to VMware ESXi myself, but I am trying to research alternative solutions to the expensive VMware licensing for failover.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really a development question, better to post this on serverfault.com

Comment: You know, I thought I was on serverfault. I apologize greatly. If there is a way to delete the question, I would do so.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Veeam Backup & Replication.